# Fast detection of transient temperature change.. RTD? Thermistors? Thermocouples? or something else?

Tags: temperature, infrared, thermistor, thermocouple, rtd

If I want to detect temperature changes on the order of 10ms, what is the best technology to use (besides IR)?

I know Thermocouples and RTDs are pretty slow.. not sure about Thermistors.

Comment: A thermistor is not all that different from a RTD. What kind of temperature change are you looking for in 10 ms? Do you need it to be 60 % of the actual temperature after 10 ms or some other value?

Comment: yes 60% is fine.. looking to track rate of combustion

Comment: Is there a reason not to use an infrared sensor?

Comment: @Arsenal the problem with the IR sensor is, that it is too large.. need something at most the size of a dice.

Comment: You know [thermopile](http://www.heimannsensor.com/Datasheet%20HCS%20Cxy%20Fz.pdf) sensors? It's just a 4x4 mm package, sure you need some electronic to interface it, but I think you can get it pretty small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: it depends.  The response time has more to do with thermal mass and thermal conductivity, and little to do with electrical principles of thermocouples, thermistors, RTDs.

If a sensor (of either type) has large thermal mass, it will take longer to equilibrate the temperature with the medium that it's measuring.  If a sensor is insulated from the medium, then it will have a slower response.  A sensor in water or oil will have a faster response than in air.

For example a thermocouple made with hair-thin wires will respond very quickly.  An industrial ungrounded thermoucouple probe will be slower.

**edit:**

> looking to track rate of combustion

I've heard that thin exposed thermocouples are used in the automotive industry for this type of measurement.  I've also heard that such thermocouples don't last long because combustion gases corrode them.  Having said that, I don't know in which part of the engine this was done.

Comment: [Omega thermocouple](http://www.omega.com/pptst/IRCO_CHAL_P13R_P10R.html) provide a table where the gage and different conditions are tested, with water they can get as low as 2 ms and in still air, they claim 50 ms.

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple silicon diode. When biased (e.g. at 1 mA), the voltage will fall at about -2 mV/deg. C. You may need to calibrate it.